# How to override a javascript namespace function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, we have this function inside a namespace which is basically called when a message event occurs.

```
window.myNameSpace = (function() {

   window.addEventListener("message", methodA, false);

   function methodA(event) {
     //some content
   }

})();
```

Now I need to override this methodA in a different javascript file to do some different work when running in different module. I tried using prototype and other stuff but they didn't work. So any reference or example for the same would be very useful.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You can't override it, but you can delete it and readd a new event listener separately. This requires you to store a reference to that method though, and I doubt you want to do that.

Comment: You will not be able to do it.

Comment: if this function is not exported with this module, you just can't do that because of **closure**.

Comment: @zfrisch How would you override it, you have no reference to `methodA` anymore.  It can't be done.

Comment: @zfrisch: The function cannot be removed from another file since it doesn't have a reference to the function.

Comment: yes I know, you are right, I edited to point that out a split second before you both commented. .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try in some different way if not by overriding. Cannot change the current namespace content though. :(

Comment: @zero298 How can I modify this namespace function so it may become public and I may be able to override it.

Comment: @zfrisch How can I modify this namespace function so it may become public and I may be able to override it?

Comment: Take it out of the IIFE?